# Grails Urlmapping 404 for group

Tags: grails

I organized my url mappings in grails with groups.

Example from UrlMappings:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    group "/rest", {
        "/" {
            controller = "rest"
            action = "index"
        }
        "/method1" {
            controller = "rest"
            action = "method1"
        }           
    }
    "/webservice/" {
        controller = "webservice"
        action = "index"
    }
}
```

What I want: When the Url is called /rest/notexists, I want a 404 for this path. But only for /rest group, so the 404 should belong to the group rest. Other 404 are handled by my backbone router.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to define a "404( ... )" mapping nested inside the `group '/rest'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a catch all at the end of the rest group:

```
 "/**" {
            controller = "rest"
            action ="notFound"
 }
```